# Equation of motion of an auxiliary field

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, supersymmetry, variational-principle, action

I'm a newbie in the field of QFT and SUSY, so I'm warning you: this might be a stupid question.

I'm working with auxiliary fields to describe supersymmetric models and I understand that upon eliminating the auxiliary field $A$ in the (first order) Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_{1}$ you need to solve his equation of motion. Substituting this in $\mathcal{L}_{1}$ gives you the second-order Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_{2}$.

Now, assume

$$\mathcal{L}_{1} = \int^{A}\!\mathrm{d}q ~F(q) - Ay(\phi)$$

The equation of motion for $A$ then gives:

$$\partial_{A}\mathcal{L}_{1} = F(A) - y(\phi) = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad A = F^{-1}(y)$$

Now, where I get confused is: can you also say that $\partial^{2}_{A}\mathcal{L}_{1} = 0$ because

$$\partial^{2}_{A}\mathcal{L}_{1} = \partial_{A} F(A) = \partial_{A}y(\phi) = 0~  ?$$

I'm not comfortable with substituting the EOM of the auxiliary field in the second step because this is maybe something from the second order Lagrangian which you cannot use here...?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most enlightening is just to show how it goes in OP's example.

1. If the Lagrangian reads
   $${\cal L}_1(A,\phi)~:= ~{\cal F}(A)- Ay(\phi),\qquad  F~=~{\cal F}^{\prime}(A),\tag{1}$$
   then the eom for the "auxiliary" variable $A$ reads
   $$ F(A)~\approx~ y(\phi) \qquad \Leftrightarrow\qquad A~\approx~ F^{-1}(y(\phi)),\tag{2}$$
   where we have assume that $F$ is an invertible function. [The equation of motion (eom) means the [EL equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation). The $\approx$ symbol means here equal modulo the eom.]
   Note that eom is *not* preserved under differentiation wrt. to field variables.  [E.g. assume the opposite is the case. Then differentiation of eq. (2)
   wrt. $A$ leads to the contradiction $1=0$.]
2. Eliminating the "auxiliary" $A$-variable in the Lagrangian (1) leads to a new Lagrangian for the remaining variable $\phi$:
   $$\begin{align}{\cal L}_2(\phi)~:=~& {\cal L}_1(F^{-1}(y(\phi)),\phi)\cr
   ~=~&{\cal F}(F^{-1}(y(\phi)))- y(\phi)F^{-1}(y(\phi)).\end{align}\tag{3}$$

The main point is that the new eom for $\phi$ using the new Lagrangian (3) remains the same as the old eom for $\phi$ using the old Lagrangian (1) if we eliminate the "auxiliary" $A$-variable from the old eom using eq. (2).

Comment: OK, I understand this. But still, my question, is $\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}_{1}}{\partial A^{2}} = 0$ true?

Comment: No,  $\frac{\partial^{2}\mathcal{L}_{1}(A,\phi)}{\partial A^{2}} = F^{\prime}(A)\approx F^{\prime}(F^{-1}(y(\phi)))$.

Comment: This is were I get confused: why should $\mathcal{L}_{1}$ and $\mathcal{L}_{2}$ be any different? You just substitute the _solution_ of A in $\mathcal{L}_{1}$ to get $\mathcal{L}_{2}$... And clearly $\partial^{2}_{A}\mathcal{L}_{2} = 0$ is true...

Comment: One is not allowed to ask questions about the "auxiliary" $A$-variable in the ${\cal L}_2$-formulation. The "auxiliary" $A$-variable has been eliminated from the formalism. If one is interested in the auxiliary sector, one should use the ${\cal L}_1$-formulation.